# List posts in WordPress with Key which is the post id

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function in WordPress that lists the ids of custom meta posts in WordPress and the function for the current user meta function. Query:

```
<?php
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'todo_listing', 
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'order'=>'asc' 
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => $id,
                'meta_value_num' => '1',
            )
    ));
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>      

<?php
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<?php echo get_the_ID();?> 

<?php
    endwhile;
?>
```

I want to list all posts with the Key which is the id of the post and that has key value 1.

The above code do not work. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$id = get_queried_object_id();

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'todo_listing', 
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'order'=>'asc' 
    'meta_key' => $id,
    'meta_value_num' => '1',
);
```